# JUnit setUp doesn't create object

Tags: java, junit

Why do I get a `NullPointerExeption` for `testManuscript` when trying to run my test?

This is my Manuscript.java:

```
package org.lhoffjann;


public class Manuscript {
private String msID;
private String path;
    public void setMSid(String msID){
        this.msID = msID;
    }

    public String getMSid() {
        return this.msID;
    }
}
```

This is my ManuscriptTest.java:

```
package org.lhoffjann;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

public class ManuscriptTest {
    private static Manuscript testManuscript;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        testManuscript = new Manuscript();
    }
    @Test
    public void testGetMSid() {
        testManuscript.setMSid("1234");
        assertTrue("1234" == testManuscript.getMSid());
    }
}
```

Comment: A sidenote (both answers are excellent here): `"1234" == testManuscript.getMSId()` __does not work__ - that is comparing reference identity, not value equality. It's `"1234".equals(testManuscript.getMSid())`, however, the better way is `assertEquals("1234", testManuscript.getMSid())`, as now JUnit will show you character-by-character where the differences are, if any. Also, `getMSid()` is not the proper style. It'd be `getMsId()`. Java code style dictates: `.getDvdPlayer()`, not `.getDVDPlayer()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have imported `@Test` from JUnit 5, while you're using `@Before` from JUnit 4, that combination doesn't work. You need to choose which JUnit version you want to use, 4 or 5, and then consistently import classes from that JUnit version. I would recommend using JUnit 5, and removing all JUnit 4 dependencies from your classpath, or at least configure your IDE to not suggest those imports.

For this specific case, replace `@Before` (`org.junit.Before`) with `@BeforeEach` (`org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach`).

In the example as shown, you don't even need this `setUp` method, as each test-execution gets its own instance of the test class. You can use:

```
private Manuscript testManuscript = new Manuscript();
```

That is, remove `static`, initialize the field directly, and remove the `setUp` method.

Even if you continue to use the `setUp` method, I recommend removing the `static`, so `testManuscript` is an instance field, like it is actually used.

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed Junit4 with Junit5. You should use only one version.

Junit4 or

```
package org.lhoffjann;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import org.junit.Assert;

public class ManuscriptTest {
    private static Manuscript testManuscript;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        testManuscript = new Manuscript();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testGetMSid() {
        testManuscript.setMSid("1234");
       Assert.assertEquals("1234",testManuscript.getMSid());
    }
```

or

Junit5

```
package org.lhoffjann;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class ManuscriptTest {
    private static Manuscript testManuscript;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        testManuscript = new Manuscript();
    }

    @Test
    void testGetMSid() {
        testManuscript.setMSid("1234");
        Assertions.assertEquals("1234", testManuscript.getMSid());
    }
}
```